# FTP closes due to multiple connection

Tags: nautilus, ftp, filemanager

I am having trouble with file transfer from our offsite FTP server. What happen was every time I try to copy multiple files, it closes after a few seconds then it blocks me for a few minutes before it allows me to reconnect. I reported it to our network admin and he said it was due to multiple connection limit has been reached.

The thing is when he checked where the connection came from it all point back to my IP. Does my file manager creates a new connection for each file? How can I transfer files without exhausting my connection limit? I'm using the default file manager for ubuntu 16.04 Files 3.14.3 [nautilus?]...

EDIT: Files are less than 100kb - 1MB each and I try to copy a directory filled with 30-50 files at a time...

Also it prompt I don't have permission to archive folders so I can't compress it to a tar file for 1 time transfer

EDIT2: I can however transfer *IN* to it a tar file and extract the content, so that solves file transfer in, but not out...

Answer (score 0):

Just use FTP client different from nautilus. FileZilla is working almost perfect. There you may do a fine tunning on your files queue, limits and etc.